# NPM install PhantomJS error on centOS 6.2

Tags: installation, npm, phantomjs

```
[root@dev ~]# npm install phantomjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phantomjs

...

npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/phantomjs/-/phantomjs-1.9.7-15.tgz
npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! not ok code 0

[root@dev ~]# node -v
v0.10.28

[root@dev ~]# npm -v
1.1.63
```

OS: centOS 6.2(final)

What is the problem? How do I install phantomjs on centOS 6.2?

Comment: I opened an issue there: https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/274

Comment: Solved it by running `npm cache clean`

Answer (score 2):

According to this: http://phantomjs.org/build.html

```
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++ make git openssl-devel freetype-devel fontconfig-devel
git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
cd phantomjs
git checkout 1.9
./build.sh
```

You can also try the pre compiled version, it would be much faster:

http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: So, you are suggesting that OP compiles phantomjs instead of installing it through npm?

Comment: If OP only needs a way to install PhantomJS, so yes. It's not the best solution, but it worked for me here. He can also try the pre compiled binary version (edit).

Answer (score 2):

Likely you don't have this error anymore as versions have advanced greatly. However, if anyone has errors on CentOS 6 running phantomJS, I found http://www.sameerhalai.com/blog/how-to-install-phantomjs-on-a-centos-server/ helpful and solved my problem. Namely, `grunt test` yielded:

```
-sh-4.1$ grunt test
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.28 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start PhantomJS

INFO [launcher]: Trying to start PhantomJS again (1/2).
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start PhantomJS

INFO [launcher]: Trying to start PhantomJS again (2/2).
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start PhantomJS

ERROR [launcher]: PhantomJS failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

but after

```
yum install -y freetype fontconfig
```

PhantomJS started working and tests passed :)